# nltk.app.concordance() crashes IDLE on Mac OS

Tags: macos, nltk, python-idle, python-3.6

I'm going through Chapter 5 in the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) and at the end of section 2.3 there's a mention of `nltk.app.concordance()`. I wanted to try this out but as soon as I went to execute the command in the IDLE Shell, the shell restarted and I got an error message to report the problem to Apple. I'm on a Mac using El Capitan and Python 3.6.0 with the all the appropriate software installed. Is this a common problem? Or something I'm doing? I've been following the book exactly.

Comment: Have you tried it outside IDLE, eg. in a plain interactive session or in a script?

Comment: If you're on a mac, use the terminal instead of IDLE, it'll lessen your pain =)

Comment: Also, `nltk` support for Py 3.6 might not be stable (for now).

Comment: @lenz I've tried a script as well, same result. I can't even import nltk and try calling the help command on it without it crashing.

Comment: @alvas I'm in a computational linguistics class and this is how we're learning things (in the Shell & in 3.6 w/NLTK) and this is the first problem like this I've run into.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `help()` in a script. How did you execute the script? With IDLE?

Comment: Yes I executed the code in the script. And I'm sorry my wording was a bit confusing, I tried the `help()` command in IDLE.

Comment: *How* did you execute the script? Did you open a terminal (not IDLE) and run `python3 <script-name.py>`? I'm asking because I suspect the `app` doesn't cope well with IDLE.

Comment: @alvas What kind of problems do you expect from running NLTK with Python 3.6? Wouldn't that mean that features are being used that have been deprecated since at least 3.4? Wouldn't that show up in the unit tests?

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message.  What version of tcl/tk are you using?  Clicking `Help => About IDLE` will tell you.  Did you update tcl/tk as specified here: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/.  Also copy and paste the minimal code needed to get the error.  I might be as little as an import and call.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I'm using TCL/TK 8.5.18 as recommended via the link you provided. I would provide the error message except I don't get an error message. The Shell simply restarts and I get Mac's "Python has quit unexpectedly" reporting screen.

Comment: @lenz I've never run scripts in Terminal before, so I don't know where to even put my script to run it in terminal/how to properly access it from where I have it in my Documents folder.

Comment: In a terminal, rerun a minimal `nltktest.py` both directly with python, `python3 nltktest.py`, and with IDLE, `python3 -m idlelib nltktest.py`.  Later will load in editor and hit F5.  You should see some error message either way.

Comment: You should really learn to use the terminal as a backup.  Apple should have intro or search web for something like "Mac OSX Terminal basics".  Once you have it up, leave file where is it and change the active directory to directory containing file.  I believe `cd` works on *nix as well as Windows.

Comment: @lenz yes, the warnings and errors are showing up on unit tests and doc tests but no one has looked into them as yet.

Comment: @alvas Oh I see. Well yes, it's a big hunk of code...

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, but I've since discovered that I can't use any of the NLTK apps. So anything beginning with  `nltk.app` crashes my Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem.
On Mac OS, for me, the only way to launch nltk.app.concordance() is from a jupyter notebook

[image: NLTK POS Part-of-Speech Concordance app]

Comment: I've never heard of jupyter, what is it?

Comment: Jupyter is an interactive interface in which we can combine python code, output from code execution, plots. It interprets python

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have to remember that the window opens up behind my browser and that the notebook cell looks like it's continually running while the app is open!